# Concatenating multiline strings while preserving the style of each one

Tags: python, string, string-concatenation

I want to concatenate two triangle :

```
 # #   + # # = # # # #
 #       #     #  #
```

So i wrote this :

```
i="""# #
#"""
print(i+i)
```

but I got this :

```
##
###
#
```

witch is what was expectable but i was wondering if there wasn't some way of concatenating strings that would preserve their styles individually ?
like this :

```
1- # # + # # ==> # # # #
2- #   + #   ==> #   #
```

To add the first line of the first multiline to the first lin of the second one, then the two last ones.
Thanks

Comment: Your question may need some more specific conditions, but what about `print('\n'.join([i,i]))`? The reason I'm joining with `\n` is because your string does not END with a newline, so that's why its not part of the cumulative addition

Comment: Your question is unclear (please provide the expected output). But I think you want to concatenate each line individually.

Comment: It's kinda hard to ask a good question but I provided the expected output

Answer (score 0):

Just add a new line between concatenations:

```py
print(i + '\n' + i)
```

Hope it helped!

Comment: thanks for the help, but it doesn't really produce what I want, I changed a little bit my question so I hope you will understand what I want to express